# how to input two decimal number

Tags: java, floating-point, decimal

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class DecimalFormatExample
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

    double number1;
    double number2;
    double number3;

    System.out.print("Insert first number:");
    number1=input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Insert second number:");
    number2=input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Insert third number:");
    number3=input.nextInt();

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    System.out.println(df.format(number1));
    System.out.println(df.format(number2));
    System.out.println(df.format(number3));
}}
```

when i insert the first number for example:

```
Insert first number:1
```

it will print out `1.00`

if i insert the number `Insert first number:1.00`, i get error. How can i put insert the number with decimal point?

Comment: Look for alternatives to `nextInt()`

Comment: Try `nextDouble()` instead of `nextInt()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote `number1=input.nextInt();` but "1.00" is not an int; it is a double. Try `number1=input.nextDouble();` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
number1 = input.nextDouble();